# UIScrollView Controller - changing a scrollview property from a nested nib?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm currently working on an application which uses a scrollViewController as I need to have a vertical and horizontal scroll so it loads the NIB's nested.

This all worked fine but when I add a UIPicker into one of my nested nibs it does not scroll, I have read this can easily be fixed by disabling scrolling in the UIScrollView however I am not 100% sure how to do this from the other class.

scrollViewController.h

```
@interface scrollViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{

    UIScrollView* scrollView;
    UIPageControl* pageControl;

    UIScrollView *vScrollView;
    UIScrollView *hScrollView;

    BOOL pageControlBeingUsed;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView* scrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPageControl* pageControl;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *vScrollView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *hScrollView;

- (IBAction)changePage;

@end
```

scrollViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;

    // main guy is a horizontal scroller
    hScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    hScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width * 2, bounds.size.height);
    hScrollView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:hScrollView];

    // the horizontal scroller contains a vertical scroller
    vScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:bounds];
    vScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.height * 2);
    vScrollView.delegate = self;
    [hScrollView addSubview:vScrollView];


    2ndView *view2 = [[2ndView alloc] initWithNibName:@"2ndView" bundle:nil];
    [vScrollView addSubview:view2.view];
    vScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, bounds.size.height);

    mainView *vc = [[mainView alloc] initWithNibName:@"mainView" bundle:nil];
    vc.view.frame = CGRectOffset(bounds, 0, bounds.size.height); 
    [vScrollView addSubview:vc.view];


    // 3rd View
    ValidatorView *vc3 = [[ValidatorView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ValidatorView" bundle:nil];
    vc3.view.frame = CGRectOffset(bounds, bounds.size.width, 0); 

    [hScrollView addSubview:vc3.view]; 

    // enable paging in both directions
    hScrollView.pagingEnabled = TRUE;
    vScrollView.pagingEnabled = TRUE;

    hScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
    vScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = FALSE;
    hScrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = FALSE;
    vScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = FALSE;
    vScrollView.canCancelContentTouches =   NO;
    vScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;    
    hScrollView.bounces = FALSE;
    vScrollView.bounces = FALSE;
}
```

In mainView.m I have created a button which brings a UIPicker onto the view, however I want it to update the vScrollView in scrollViewController with the property

vScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Thanks Aaron

Answer (score 0):

You can have an instance variable in your application delegate class that points to your scrollViewController and then you can use `scrollEnabled` of that instance variable to `NO`

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can do this?

Comment: You can reache the application delegate anywhere in the application like this 

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]`(Set it to your application's delegate variable )

If you have a property in your AppDelegate like

`@property ( nonatomic,retain ) UIScrollViewController * yourScrollController;`

Whenever you create the scrollViewController set it to yourScrollController. 

Then when you want to disable it just do this.

MyAppDelegate(whatever its name is)* del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];`

`del.yourScrollController.vScrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;`

Like this.

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense just one extra question my application delegate loads the scrollViewController as a view and that is where the properties are? do I need to change how this works as currently I don't think there is any direct connection from app delegate.

Comment: If you are just creating and pushing that view without saving it any global variables ( I mean property or variables of app delegate ) you need to add a property to save it. If you are already doing it you can use that property to access your scrollViews.

Comment: Hi Sorry to be a pain in AppDelegate it currently loads the scrollViewController in didFinishLaunching     [window addSubview:scrollViewController.view];
 [window makeKeyAndVisible]; just struggling to work out how I get the connect from appDelegate to the View?